# call to create action via different button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

ive MVC 5 app that in the index page you have a table ,how should I call from the index page to the create action in the controller not in the default button.
the default button is doing this like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

but my table is behave little bit different 
and I use the following button

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()" class="data-button" id="add-row" />
```

How from this button I call to the create action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, give your 'Create' button an `id` so that it can be easily identified:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { id = "create-button" })
```

Then on click of the `Add` button get the `href` from that button and redirect the page:

```js
function add() {
    window.location.assign($('#create-button').prop('href'));
}
```

If you would prefer to attach the event to the `Add` button in jQuery try this:

```html
<input type="button" value="Add" class="data-button" id="add-row" />
```

```js
$('#add-row').click(function() {
    window.location.assign($('#create-button').prop('href'));
});
```

Comment: `#create` = `#create-button`? :)

Comment: Thanks but how should I connect it to the following button that when you click on it the create action will be invoked

<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()" class="data-button" id="add-row" />

Comment: @shopiaT You are calling the `add()` function on click of that button.

Comment: With jQuery it is recommended you do not use `onClick` attributes. The better approach is to leave any inputs code-free and select them from jQuery to add event handlers. This also allows for multiple events to be added.

Comment: What TrueBlueAussie says is correct, I updated my answer to show you how you can trap the event in jQuery.

Comment: Thank you very much,I try to play with it and I've two problem 1.Now I see in the UI two buttons.2.When I click on create it open for me the create view which I dont want it I just want it to call to the action create in the controller....

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to call action method using input button. I have added two of them as below.

1.You can call the action using the javascript. You can add following javascript function.

> ```
> <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()" class="data-button" id="add-row" />
> function add()
> {
>     window.location = @Url.Action("Create");
> }
> ```

2.Using Form element. If you will put button inside some form then it will be post on specified url, when user click on the button.

> ```
> @using (Html.BeginForm("Create"))
> {
>     <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()" class="data-button" id="add-row" />
> }
> ```

Comment: With jQuery it is recommended you do not use `onClick` attributes. The better approach is to leave any inputs *code-free* and select them from jQuery to add event handlers. This also allows for multiple events to be added.

Comment: Yeah, you can use jQuery as well.

Comment: Got to be careful with Razor JS injection. You are missing some quotes around the injected part of `window.location = @Url.Action("Create");`. Without them you create a JavaScript error.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do like this to invoke it:

### HTML:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", null, new { id = "linkCreate" })

<input type="button" value="Add" class="data-button" id="add-row" />
```

You have to write event of button click and in its function, invoke that link using [**click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

### JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#add-row").click(function(event){

    $("#linkCreate").click();

   event.preventDefault();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a $.Post like this

```
$('#add-row').click(function(){
    // data is the values that you are passing to the controller
    // '/Index/Create' is the Url of the action - Area/Controller/Action
   $.post('/Index/Create',data,function(){
        // This is the code for success function
         alert("new record has been added successfully");
   });
});
```